# How to clear vector in C++ from memory

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ so this may be a newbie question however I'm not entirely clear how to clear it from memory. I've searched online and looked are several answers but was unclear on how to properly execute what im trying to do.

How can i clear my vector from memory correctly in c++? Thanks and i apologize if this is a dup post.

```
vector<ElementData> Elements;
```

As mentioned by a comment below, i would like to return the memory used as well.

> except that it will not return any memory to the system as the
>   capacity remains unchanged.

Comment: Do you want the vectors capacity to back to zero or do you want the vector itself to b gone?

Comment: Do you want to clear the elements stored in the vector from memory, or do you want to clear the vector object itself from memory?

Comment: Is this some security-related question?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you want to reset you vector back to a empty state then we can use the `swap` trick to swap the contents of the vector into a temporary that will get destroyed and free the memory

```
vector<ElementData> Elements
// fill the vector up
vector<ElementData>().swap(Elements);
```

This will create a temporary empty vector, swap it with the one you have so now it is empty and then destroy everything in the temporary vector.

You can see it working in this little example

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> foo(500);
    std::cout << foo.capacity() << std::endl;
    std::vector<int>().swap(foo);
    std::cout << foo.capacity() << std::endl;
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42d7f108d629ff5d)</kbd>

Comment: thank you for your help.

Comment: Why not just `Elements = vector<ElementData>();`?

Comment: @ChristianHackl That should work but I worry that the vector would still be able to keep its capacity.  I am not sure what the standard has to say about that.

Comment: @NathanOliver I understand that the inverse swap operation, such as `Elements.swap(vector<ElementData>())` should be semantically equivalent to `vector<ElementData>().swap(Elements)`, right?

Comment: @Peregring-lk `Elements.swap(vector<ElementData>())` wont work because `swap` has a `vector &` parameter, so it cannot bind to the temporary `vector<ElementData>()` creates.

Comment: @NathanOliver right, haven't thought of that. Do you know if there is any reason why swap doesn't accept a rvalue-reference? That would allow that pattern. Writting the temporary as argument is more descriptive in my opinion.

Comment: @Peregring-lk No I do not.  FWIW, Making a function like `template <typename... Params> void clear_vector_memory(std::vector<Params...>& vec) { vector<Params...>().swap(vec); }` might be even better.  That way your code just becomes `clear_vector_memory(my_vector);`

Answer (score 17):

std::vector variables are normally destructed automatically when you go out of scope, or when the class object they are members of are destroyed. The destructor of std::vector also destroys all elements in the vector.

To completely clear a vector explicitly, first clear the vector (destroy the elements)

```
v.clear()
```

then return the memory previously reserved for the vector elements

```
v.shrink_to_fit();
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit

Only call `shrink_to_fit` if it's likely that the vector previously contained far more elements than you are going to fill it with.

Comment: FYI `shrink_to_fit` is not required to do anything so it may or may not work.

Comment: Yes, but allocations are not observable under the as-if rule, so it would be hard for the standard to have a stronger wording. I'm not aware of any C++11 compliant compiler with a no op shrink_to_fit. VS and gcc have ´real´ ones for sure.

Answer (score 3):

When your program ends, `vector`'s dtor will get called and delete your vector for you, since you've allocated it on the stack. Furthermore, the dtor for `ElementData` will get called for each one in the vector.

Comment: great information thank you Chara.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, the best way is to limit the scope of the vector to where it's actually needed. So, instead of something like:

```
vector<Elements> Elements;
... do some work with Elements ...
Elements.clear(); // or whatever "trick" you want to use
... do more work where Elements is not needed ...
```

You would do this:

```
{ // begin a new scope
    vector<Elements> Elements;
    ... do some work with Elements ...
} // Elements is now out of scope, its memory has been freed
... do more work where Elements is not needed ...
```

The other benefit of this is that after `Elements` has gone out of scope, you can't accidentally reuse it. If the function is small, you probably don't need to create a new explicit scope. Returning from the function will have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything special. Since both the vector and the elements inside are statically allocated (i.e. not created by new), when the vector gets out of scope, it's deallocated and the destructor gets called on all ElementData inside.  If you would have `vector<ElementData*>`, where the vector only contains pointers to ElementData, then you would also have to `delete` all the ElementData yourself.

Answer (score -5):

`Elements.clear()` will do what you want.

[Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) are the rest of the functions available to vectors.

Comment: except that it will not return any memory to the system as the capacity remains unchanged.

Comment: @NathanOliver how can i return the memory correctly?

Comment: Generally you don't need to. If you really feel you need to, you can try calling [shrink_to_fit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit).