# Confused with c++ swap function: std::vector<int>().swap(search_indices);

Tags: c++, stdvector, swap

Here is the code, I am very confused. `swap` function is usually used to exchange the value of two parameters, like `a.swap(b)` or `swap(a, b)`. What is the meaning of `swap` here?

```
std::vector<int> search_indices;
        std::vector<float> distances;

        int keypointNum = 0;
        do
        {
            keypointNum++;
            std::vector<int>().swap(search_indices);
            std::vector<float>().swap(distances);

            int id;
            iterUnseg = unVisitedPtId.begin();
            id = *iterUnseg;
            indices->indices.push_back(features[id].ptId);
            unVisitedPtId.erase(id);

            tree.radiusSearch(features[id].pt, _curvature_non_max_radius, search_indices, distances);

            for (int i = 0; i < search_indices.size(); ++i)
            {
                unVisitedPtId.erase(search_indices[i]);
            }

        } while (!unVisitedPtId.empty());
```

I have looked for how `swap` function works, no related explanations.

Comment: Not sure if this should be a dupe or not but see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35514909/how-to-clear-vector-in-c-from-memory/35515040#35515040

Comment: here swap swaps the two parameters. It is `a.swap(b)`

Comment: `std::vector<int>().swap(search_indices)` is equivalent to `std::swap(std::vector<int>(), search_indices)`. It's basically an obfuscated way of doing `search_indices.clear()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear vector in C++ from memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35514909/how-to-clear-vector-in-c-from-memory)

Comment: Or in other words it swaps your vector with a new empty one.

Answer (score 5):

Given `std::vector<int> v;` definition, `std::vector<int>().swap(v);` clears vector `v` and disposes of the memory it reserved (so that `v.capacity()` returns 0). Starting from C++11, an arguably better way to write it is:

```
v.clear();
v.shrink_to_fit();
```

Comment: ["It is a **non-binding** request to reduce capacity() to size(). It depends on the implementation whether the request is fulfilled. "](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit). `shrink_to_fit` potentially changes nothing about the vectors capactiy. Swapping like in OPs code is guaranteed to end up with a empty vector with empty capacity

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number While using `shrink_to_fit` isn't strictly guaranteed to reduce capacity, any rational implementation will work as intended in this case (with a size of 0). The reason it is non-binding is to provide leeway for implementations to shrink capacity to whatever value fits their allocation scheme (ex. power of 2 or whatever they use for amortized resize).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux ok, actually I had in mind that `shrink_to_fit` was already older and that the swapping was to overcome the "non-binding". Seems like that was wrong, and the swapping was just the <c++11 way.

Answer (score 2):

It is a trick to clear a vector and free all the allocated memory for its elements.

In these statements

```
std::vector<int>().swap(search_indices);
std::vector<float>().swap(distances);
```

there are used empty temporary created vectors, `std::vector<int>()` and `std::vector<float>()`, that are swapped with the vectors `search_indices` and `distances`.

After the calls of the member function `swap` the both vectors `search_indices` and `distances` become empty. In turn the temporary vectors that after the swapping contain the elements of the above two vectors will be destroyed.

This trick is used because if you will just write

```
search_indices.clear();
distances.clear();
```

the allocated memory can be preserved. That is the member function `capacity` can return a non-zero value.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    std::cout << "v.size() = " << v.size() << '\n';
    std::cout << "v.capacity() = " << v.capacity() << '\n';

    std::cout << '\n';

    v.clear();

    std::cout << "v.size() = " << v.size() << '\n';
    std::cout << "v.capacity() = " << v.capacity() << '\n';

    std::cout << '\n';

    std::vector<int>().swap( v );

    std::cout << "v.size() = " << v.size() << '\n';
    std::cout << "v.capacity() = " << v.capacity() << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
v.size() = 5
v.capacity() = 5

v.size() = 0
v.capacity() = 5

v.size() = 0
v.capacity() = 0
```

As you can see after calling the member function `swap` with the temporary empty vector the capacity of the vector `v` becomes equal tp 0.

To get the same effect using the method `clear` you should after calling it also to call the method  `shrink_to_fit()`. For example

```
v.clear();
v.shrink_to_fit();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a strategy to free up memory. I wrote a test code here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> test(9, 0);
    std::cout <<test.size() << std::endl;
    std::vector<int>().swap(test);
    std::cout <<test.size() << std::endl;
    cout<<"Hello World";

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

> 9
> 0
> Hello World

Comment: You need to check `test.capacity()` to see if the vector freed some memory