std::vector not clearing memory or bad custom allocator?
I ma trying to write a memory tracking class, which will help me to track memory consumption.
I created an std::vector with my custom allocator and noticed that vector does not free memory on std::vector::clear. Is it OK, or it is something wring with my allocator?
If it is normal situation, how can I force vector to free memory?
Here is my code. It is based partially on chatgpt and partially on this resource: https://johnfarrier.com/custom-allocators-in-c-high-performance-memory-management/
main.cpp:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "memory.hpp"

int main()
{
    {
        std::cout << "\ncreating vector\n";
        data::vector<short int> v;
        std::cout << "\nreserving 100 elements\n";
        v.reserve(100);
        std::cout << data::MemoryTracker::Bytes_in_use() << " bytes allocated\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            v.push_back(i);
        }
        std::cout << "\npushing one extra element\n";
        v.push_back(0);
        std::cout << "\nclearing vector\n";
        v.clear();
        std::cout << data::MemoryTracker::Bytes_in_use() << " bytes allocated\n";
        v.resize(0);
        std::cout << "\npushing 1 element\n";
        v.push_back(0);
        std::cout << data::MemoryTracker::Bytes_in_use() << " bytes allocated\n";

        std::cout << "\nleaving scope\n";
    }
    std::cout << data::MemoryTracker::Bytes_in_use() << " bytes allocated\n";

    return 0;
}

memory.hpp:
#ifndef _MEMORY_HPP_
#define _MEMORY_HPP_
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
namespace data{
class MemoryTracker
{
    template <typename T>
    friend class TrackingAllocator;

private:
    static _NODISCARD void *allocate(size_t size)
    {
        std::cout << "allocating " << size << " bytes\n";
        bytes_in_use += size;
        return std::malloc(size);
    }

    static void deallocate(void *ptr, size_t size)
    {
        std::cout << "freeing " << size << " bytes\n";
        bytes_in_use -= size;
        std::free(ptr);
        // ::operator delete[](ptr);
    }
public:
    static size_t Bytes_in_use() { return bytes_in_use; }

private:
    static size_t bytes_in_use;
};

size_t MemoryTracker::bytes_in_use = 0;

template <typename T>
class TrackingAllocator
{
    // friend class MemoryTracker;

public:
    friend bool operator==(const TrackingAllocator &, const TrackingAllocator &) { return true; }
    friend bool operator!=(const TrackingAllocator &, const TrackingAllocator &) { return false; }

public:
    using value_type = T;
    using pointer = T *;
    using const_pointer = const T *;
    using reference = T &;
    using const_reference = const T &;
    using size_type = size_t;
    using difference_type = ptrdiff_t;

    TrackingAllocator() = default;
    template <typename U>
    TrackingAllocator(const TrackingAllocator<U> &) {};

    _NODISCARD pointer allocate(size_type n)
    {
        return static_cast<pointer>(MemoryTracker::allocate(n * sizeof(value_type)));
    }

    void deallocate(pointer p, size_type n)
    {
        MemoryTracker::deallocate(p, n * sizeof(value_type));
    }

    template <typename U, typename... Args>
    void construct(U *p, Args &&...args)
    {
        ::new ((void *)p) U(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    void destroy(pointer p) noexcept {
        p->~value_type();
    }
};
template <class _Ty>
class vector : public std::vector<_Ty, TrackingAllocator<_Ty>>{};
}

#endif


A side note: it's usually not a good idea to inherit from std::vector. See: Thou shalt not inherit from std::vector.

There's no requirements for an allocator to release memory back to the OS. Or for the OS to actually unmap it from the process. All that's specified, basically, is that any valid pointer that has been passed to delete or delete[] may never be dereferenced again (until assigned to point to some other valid memory).

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear => it "removes" the objects without deleting the storage (see difference between size and capacity)

try https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit

Side note: names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (_MEMORY_HPP_) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

do note that shrink_to_fit does not have to do anything.  If you want to the vector to completly empty out and release all memory then you can use the swap technique: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35515040/4342498

... and if you don't want it completely empty, but force it to shrink to fit, this may be an option: template<class... Args> void shrink_to_fit(std::vector<Args...>& v) { if(v.size() == v.capacity()) return; std::vector<Args...> nv(std::move_iterator(v.begin()), std::move_iterator(v.end())); v.swap(nv); }

@Ted Lyngmo -- unsafe if the nothrow move is not guaranteed, should do it only if std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v

@Gene Or just make the function template conditionally noexcept

@wohlstad, thank you for the link. From what i've read, it's not safe to inherit publicly, but it is OK to inherit private. Is this right? If not, how can i create a memory tracking system? I don't think that it is a good idea to write my own container from scratch.

@Victor What about doing what std::pmr does? namespace mta {
template <class T>
using vector = std::vector<T, TrackingAllocator<T>>;
} - and then use mta::vector<type> whenever you want to use your tracking allocator? No inheritance needed.

@TedLyngmo, wow, thank you! Didn't think about it.

@Victor You're welcome! Glad it helped!
